# Modelagem de parcelas e notas fiscais

Tags: banco-de-dados

Tenho as seguintes tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE projeto (
  idprojeto int not null,
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE nota_fiscal (
  idnota_fiscal int not null,
  numero int not null,
  data_emissao datetime not null,
  data_recebimento datetime not null
  ...
);

CREATE TABLE parcela(
  idparcela int not null,
  valor decimal(9,2) not null,
  numero_parcela int not null,
  idprojeto int not null,
  idnota_fiscal int not null,
  ...
);
```

Então um **projeto** pode ter muitas **parcelas** e uma **nota fiscal** pode estar relacionada com mais de uma parcela. O valor está na parcela, que é cadastrada junto com o projeto, ou seja, na mesma tela cadastro o projeto e todas as suas parcelas. Só depois cadastro a nota fiscal e associo a parcela com a nota. O valor da nota é a soma do valor das parcelas que ela está associada, porém eu só vou saber o valor da nota depois de associar todas as parcelas com a nota.

A minha dúvida é se esta modelagem está correta ou funciona bem, não sei se esta é a melhor forma de tratar os valores, pensei em talvez ter um valor para nota fiscal também, mas pensando em normalização acredito que não é correto.

Comment: Não acho que a parcela deva ficar associada ao projeto uma vez que parcela ou avisa (1 parcela) são forma de pagamentos que estão vinculadas a uma compra (projeto). Não sei todos os detalhes e regras do projeto ai, me parece mais adequado 1 projeto -> 1 nota fiscal -> 1 ou N parcelas.

Comment: Entendi. Inicialmente eu pensei dessa forma, mas fiz assim porque já tenho os valores das parcelas do projeto na hora de cadastrá-lo e preciso de alguma forma saber que estas parcelas são de determinado projeto para poder consultar.

Comment: Então parte do problema é que você tem parcelas a pagas ou a receber sem terem uma nota fiscal? aí nesse caso vc associou com o projeto?

Comment: Isso. Eu cadastro um projeto e suas parcelas com valores já definidos no contrato. E só na entrega dos projetos vou cadastrar a nota fiscal, além disso tem uma variável, geralmente é pago a primeira parcela de cada projeto em um única nota.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro criar uma coluna de valor para a nota fiscal, que é a soma de todas as parcelas, ou seja, uma **desnormalização**.  Então toda vez que for gravar uma nota fiscal, vai somar as parcelas e gravar o valor total na nota fiscal.

Certamente você precisará criar relatórios estatísticos ou gráficos para consolidar os valores, ou mesmo fazer filtros pelo valor total e nestes casos será mais simples de implementar e menos custoso para o bancos de dados, pois não precisará acessar as parcelas.

Comment: Não daria quase na mesma, já que eu já pego a soma de todas as parcelas de uma nota? Assim apenas facilitaria as consultas, né? Eu pensei na possibilidade de criar uma coluna valor_nota em nota fiscal, pensando em relatórios e gráficos, como você falou, mas acho que não daria certo também. Da forma atual funciona ou terei muitos problemas?

Comment: Fiz uma edição. Acho bastante interessante criar esta coluna e não vejo porque daria errado. Certamente vai deixar as consultar mais leves.